# Getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException exception even though i have used Mather correctly

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a service using Mockito, but it is saying i have not used argument Mather correctly.

```
import com.spmsoftware.appframework.validation.ValidationContext;
import com.spmsoftware.appframework.validation.ValidationContextSupport;
import com.spmsoftware.filters.api.model.Filter;
import com.spmsoftware.filters.api.validation.FilterValidationService;
import com.spmsoftware.tablereference.api.service.TableReferenceService;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyObject;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestInputTabValidator {
    @Mock
    private Filter filter;
    @Mock
    private TableReferenceService tableReferenceService;
    @Mock
    private FilterValidationService filterValidationService;


    @InjectMocks private InputTabValidator inputTabValidator;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        preCondition();
    }

    private void preCondition() {
        when(tableReferenceService.getTable(anyLong())).thenReturn(anyObject());
        when(tableReferenceService.tableExists(1L)).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void validateInputTabSaveWithFilter() {
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContextSupport();
        inputTabValidator.validate(new Object[]{anyLong(), filter}, validationContext);
        Assert.assertTrue("no validation errors recorded", !validationContext.hasErrors());

    }

    public void validateInputTabSaveWithoutFilter() {
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContextSupport();
        inputTabValidator.validate(new Object[]{anyLong()}, validationContext);

        Assert.assertTrue("no validation errors recorded", !validationContext.hasErrors());

    }

} 




 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
 Invalid use of argument matchers!
 1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
 -> at com.spmsoftware.genericWebservices.validator.TestInputTabValidator.preCondition(TestInputTabValidator.java:55)
 -> at com.spmsoftware.genericWebservices.validator.TestInputTabValidator.preCondition(TestInputTabValidator.java:56)

 This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
     //incorrect:
     someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
 When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
 For example:
     //correct:
     someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

 For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.


    at com.spmsoftware.genericWebservices.validator.TestInputTabValidator.preCondition(TestInputTabValidator.java:56)
    at com.spmsoftware.genericWebservices.validator.TestInputTabValidator.setUp(TestInputTabValidator.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Cause is due to `Mockito.any(MessageCreator.class)` , but isn't there a way to test my send method is getting executed without creating an actual object in the `MessageCreator`?

Comment: "Cause is due to Mockito.any(MessageCreator.class)..." This is not in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line:

```
when(tableReferenceService.getTable(anyLong())).thenReturn(anyObject());
```

You can't use a matcher as the expected return value. What you want is probably something like:

```
when(tableReferenceService.getTable(anyLong())).thenReturn(new Table());
```

or

```
Table table = mock(Table.class);
when(tableReferenceService.getTable(anyLong())).thenReturn(table);
```

depending on whether the object returned by `tableReferenceService.getTable()` requires mocking or not.